# Are bread improvers really needed?

Tags: bread, yeast, flatbread

I am new to baking and I am in the process of creating and starting my bakery in my country.

I got a few questions, my bakery is planning on making pita bread. I have a fully automatic machine that will create the bread.

I plan to product fresh bread everyday and when needed. My main fears are mold, bad texture, and taste.

My questions are:

1- Would it mold after the first (1st) day If i don't put any preservatives?

2- I really don't want to add to the cost, should I think of adding Bread Improvers, would it even help the taste?

3- Are Bread improvers that important?

Here are the ingredient:

- Brown Sugar for browning
- Baking soda to help neutralize the acidity that comes from the molasses in the brown sugar.
- Salt
- Water
- Yeast

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to start a bakery - *Have you made a few small, home-oven scale batches of the recipes you are going to sell?* If not, I strongly recommend you do so, just to get a feeling for your product (e.g. how the dough should look and feel) *before* using large batches in the machines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bread improvers that I have seen simply encourage gluten development to improve bread texture. They are often called for for use in bread machines because those machines are not as effective at kneading. Many bread improvers are as simple as extra vitamin C.
Without knowing the details of the machine you are planning to use it is difficult to say whether a bread improver would help. I would try without it. If the bread is too crumbly then add some Vitamin C.

Bread improvers do not change the flavor of the bread so much as the texture. I don't think the slight change in acidity would make much difference to the shelf life but I've not read anything about that.

Whether bread will mold in one day depends greatly on how the bread is stored and what you climate is. If it is very humid and the bread is stored uncovered then it could possibly mold after one day. If the climate is too dry then the bread could be quite stale after a day. 
There is a reason that preservative-free bread is usually sold the same day it is baked.

*Note* although not part of your question, brown sugar (and the soda to neutralize the brown sugar) are not at all required for bread to brown. A quick search for pita recipes shows either no sugar or just enough to activate the yeast in the recipe.

Comment: Here are the ratios from a bakery in Lebanon: Flour 100kg,
Water 55 liters,
Salt 400 grams,
Sugar 2.5 kg,
Yeast 1kg.